# How to import VCF 2.1 files (from Samsung phone) into Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, import, address-book

I exported a VCF 2.1 file from my Samsung phone (an A11 phone, using android 10, and the native contact software.  There are 500+ contacts.

Now, I want to import that contact list into Thunderbird; I am using the version 91.10.0 (64 bit).  On executing the import, there is an import error which ends the import after a fraction of contacts are imported.

The import bombs out on encountering a Samsung novel field -- custom telephone types. More detail, below.

I've not updated the TBird for various reasons, to version 102, but haven't noticed any release notes which address this issue, from 91 to 102.

**What I've Tried:**

I have considered importing the VCF in a roundabout fashion, but can't get the VCF out to a CSV file from the phone, or to another Excel type file.  From there, I would have hoped to get the import done one way or another.

I also can't get the VCF file into excel in a useful fashion, as the VCF format divides out field/groups with a field entry, line by line, sometimes including ";" as a field divider on various lines.

I have tried to import the VCF contact list into outlook (using my older OfficePro 2010), in the hope that i could snag that address book from Thunderbird, but I can only import the first VCF card in the file.

I also note that fabricating a CSV file, brute force, creating single lines from the multi-line vcard entries would be a mess, as would finding and modifying all the custom field names.   A no-go, for sure.

Any suggestions / solutions ?

**More Detail on the error**

The Samsung VCF file includes my custom fields for telephone types [as well as emails].  For example, within a VCard a line begins as:

> TEL;X-CUSTOM(CHARSET=UTF-8,ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE,=4B=61=72= [etc.]

When the import reaches that line in the VCF file, the error occurs, and the import stops.  The error is "Missing Parameter", but I assume the error is connected with the custom field name for telephone numbers.

I recognize that the Thunderbird contact list format does not include custom field names for phones/emails, though it does have some custom fields and a notes field.

(I would have preferred if the off-format data was just placed in the notes field, custom field name and data.)

**Error Code Provided by Thunderbird**

> uncaught exception: ParserError: Missing parameter value in 'TEL;X-CUSTOM(CHARSET=UTF-8,ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE,=4D=61=72= [etc.]'
>
> importDialog.js:956:23
>
> ImportAddress chrome://messenger/content/importDialog.js:956
>
> AsyncFunctionNext self-hosted:692
>
> toImport chrome://messenger/content/mailCore.js:521
>
> AbImport chrome://messenger/content/addressbook/addressbook.js:525
>
> oncommand chrome://messenger/content/addressbook/addressbook.xhtml:1
>
> NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: E10SUtils.jsm:654
>
> getRemoteTypeForPrincipal resource://gre/modules/E10SUtils.jsm:654

**Bugzilla**

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1766188

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: see changed question... thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The Thunderbird extension
[MoreFunctionsForAddressBook](http://www.softsea.com/review/MoreFunctionsForAddressBook.html)
is reported as enabling the import of VCF 2.1 contact files:

- Open Address Book
- Position to *Tools > MoreFunctionsForAddressBook > Actions for contacts > Import vCard/vcf*
- Select the VCF files in the 'Contact import' window
  (Ctrl-A to select all the files in a folder)
- Import the selected files.

Comment: Thanks for an answer.  However, the X-CUSTOM field is, by definition (it appears) not to the VCF standard, rather a experimental/non-standard not intended for interoperability.  (i looked, this afternoon, at a VCF format description.)   I also note that your suggested import is neither on the Mozilla site, nor supported by it s author, and appears on a non-standard site (it also has a version of Firefox, which should never be relied on...).  There is also info which suggests that the specific add on supports up to TBird version 60.

Comment: I think the real issue is that the exported VCards, on Samsung's usage, allow for custom name fields (for TEL and EMAIL) which don't even exist in TBird's contact list format.   And there is no automated way to shunt the needed data to TBird's "note" field.

Comment: I wonder, as a complete aside, what happens when TBird encounters .two. TEL lines in a VCard, where .both. have the same type "CELL".   The TBird contact list doesn't, at first glance, support two phone numbers of the same type.

Comment: If the VCF files are totally non-standard, you might consider a text-editing product to save the important fields.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, given the card-count and my propensity to put in the correct naming of the email or telephone.  But, you're right.   I'm sure notepad++ and/or word 2010 will get the job done with enough patience -- i can move the errant fields into the TBird note.